# Power series solution for $y''-xy'-y =0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I must find a power series solution for:

$$y''-xy'-y =0$$

centered at $x_0 = 0$

I'm supposing it in the form:

$$y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$

so:

$$y' = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}$$
$$y'' = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$$

I've shifted the index of all of them, so I got:

$$y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$
$$y' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}$$
$$y'' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}$$

so,substituting it in the differential equation, I get:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}-x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n = 0$$

The idea now is to group them all and isolate the $x^n$ coefficient, but what should I do with that $x$ multiplying $y'$? It'll shift the index of the sum and it'll have the term $x^{n+1}$ in it, making it impossible to isolate $x^n$

Comment: So isolate $x^{n+1}$. You might need to consider the first few values $a_0, a_1,..$ separately as they are not present in all three sums.

Comment: It's probably more efficient if you multiply the $x$ inside the sum _before_ you shift the index.

Comment: @B.Goddard but I have two choices: either I start at $n=0$ and $x^{n+1}$ or I start at $n=1$ and $x^n$, I can't do both :c

Comment: The standard way is to multiply the $x$ inside.   Then shift the index, so you end up starting at $n=1$.  Then take the $n=0$ terms out of the other two sums and move them to the front of the expression.  Now all three sums start at $n=1$.

Comment: Put the x in the middle term inside the summation and shift the index again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n$, then
$$
y'=\sum_{n\ge1}na_nx^{n-1}
$$
and
$$
y''=\sum_{n\ge2}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}=\sum_{n\ge0}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n
$$
Therefore
$$
y''-xy'-y=\sum_{n\ge0}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n-\sum_{n\ge0}na_nx^{n}-\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n
$$
so
$$
(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}-na_n-a_n=0
$$
or
$$
(n+2)a_{n+2}-a_n=0
$$